# hyperlinks into on DIV

Tags: html, css

in HTML:
how can I make different images together with its respective hyperlinks inside a `<div>`

I would like to avoid making many `<div>` entries for each image.

```
<div class="image_" data-no-elementresizer><a href="http://....." target="_self">img.jpg</a></div>

<div class="image_" data-no-elementresizer><a href="http://....." target="_self">img.jpg</a></div>

<div class="image_" data-no-elementresizer><a href="http://....." target="_self">img.jpg</a></div>
```

Comment: It's kinda hard to figure what you want to achieve here.

Answer (score 1):

Would this be something you are looking for?

```css
.gallery {
  width: 820px;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 800px;
}
.gallery img {
  float: left;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200" />
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/people/2" />
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/city/3" />
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/city/2" />
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200" />
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200" />
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/people" />
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/sports/2" />
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/city" />
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/sports" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be late but here my answer with images and hyperlinks.

```
div.image {
    margin: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    float: left;
    width: 180px;
}   

div.image :hover {
    border: 1px solid #777;
}

div.image img{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}


<div class="image">
  <a target="_self" href="Url">
    <img src="ImageUrl" width="300" height="200">
  </a>
   <a target="_self" href="Url">
    <img src="ImageUrl" width="300" height="200">
  </a> <a target="_self" href="Url">
    <img src="ImageUrl" width="300" height="200">
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you! this is exactly what I was looking for. it worked perfectly!

Comment: in relationship to the position of the images, either to have them in a vertical row or two rows, would I edit this aspect in the HTML or CSS? thank you again!

Comment: Its good that it helped you So you can Mark it as **answer**. But I can't understand your next problem. Do you want images to be aligned in vertical.